# Is it possible for user to escape asp.net core's application folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

For example file `css.css` is accessible because it should be

access url:

> localhost:1234/css.css

```
projects_folder
    - application.dll
    - wwwroot\css.css
```

but what about situation:

```
disk
     secret_folder
          - secret.txt
     application_folder
          - application.dll
          - wwwroot\css.css
```

Can I safely assume that user is unable to this `even with some tricks!`:

> localhost:1234/../secret_folder/secret.txt

in default ASP .NET Core's MVC template?

Comment: if you doesn't serve the secret files with a file provider, and also you have no middlewares/route hanlders/mvc actions to return the secret.txt , you're safe .

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the application is configured.

In the default ASP .NET Core's MVC template you should have the following in your Startup.Configure to allow access to static files in the wwwroot folder:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles(); // For the wwwroot folder
}
```

The parameterless UseStaticFiles method overload marks the files in web root (wwwroot) as servable.

In order to access static files outside of the web root you would be required to add further configuration, as described in the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x